# How do i find the effective user id (EUID), real user id (RUID) and saved user id (SUID)?

Tags: linux

I need to find the RUID, EUID and SUID of different processes. Unfortunatly I have no idea how i can find these ID`s.
Given are:
The excess permission for owner, group and the rest of the world. A number (i don`t know what for, its always the number "1") the owner, the group. Then again a number (different from each other) the modification date and the file name.

Here is an example:

-rwsr-xr--  1  anna  users  Oct  12  11:12  file3.bin

Thanks for any help! :)

Comment: Is this homework?

Answer (score 3):

These parameters belong to a *process*. Your given example describes not a process but a *file*. You'd only get a process if you ran that file as a program.

The initial effective UID (as well as the saved UID) can be guessed here: since the file has the 'setuid' flag set, and is owned by the user 'anna', running it will create a process with the effective UID of the 'anna' user.

Meanwhile, the initial real UID is *always* based on the user who ran the program and created the process. You can use `id` to see yours. In fact, you could copy `id` to a temporary place, change its owner, set the 'setuid' bit, and see what values it prints out.

However, a process may swap its real and effective UIDs, or if owned by root change them to anything. To know the UIDs of a specific process you should examine the *process* – on Linux, this can be done by reading `/proc/<pid>/status` and includes all the UIDs, GIDs, supplementary groups, and so on.